# Where is Apache's 000-default.conf in FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, freebsd, bsd

Where is Apache 2.4's 000-default.conf in FreeBSD 11?  It seems it does not exist in FreeBSD 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean `sites-enabled/000-default` Virtual Host, like in many Linux distributions. There isn't one.

In FreeBSD, as described in the [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-apache.html), `VirtualHost`s are configured directly in `/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf`; there's no `include sites-enabled/*`.

> 28.8.2. Virtual Hosting
>
> To setup Apache to use name-based virtual hosting, add a `VirtualHost`
>   block for each website. For example, for the webserver named
>   www.domain.tld with a virtual domain of www.someotherdomain.tld, add
>   the following entries to `httpd.conf`:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *>
>     ServerName www.domain.tld
>     DocumentRoot /www/domain.tld
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *>
>     ServerName www.someotherdomain.tld
>     DocumentRoot /www/someotherdomain.tld
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Comment: yes that is what I read in the handbook, why only one conf in FreeBSD?

Comment: Because they have desided so. But even when used, from the perspective of configuration it's only a wildcard include: you can still use separated configuration files, if you want. You just don't have `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` tools but you'll have to use `ln -s` and `rm` instead. I actually did so years before I figured out there are these commands; they just do it for you.